How to modify a neuron in the fully connected layer individually?
How to modify a neuron in the fully connected layer individually and design it as a statistical indicator such as kurtosis or negative entropy, as shown in the figure.

Is it just a simple calculation of the kurtosis value after the linear layer? like as:
class KurtosisNeuron(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(KurtosisNeuron, self).__init__()

    def forward(self, x):
        
        mean = torch.mean(x, dim=1, keepdim=True)
       
        second_moment = torch.mean((x - mean) ** 2, dim=1, keepdim=True)
        
        fourth_moment = torch.mean((x - mean) ** 4, dim=1, keepdim=True)
        
        kurtosis = fourth_moment / (second_moment ** 2) - 3
        return kurtosis

class CustomFC(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_features, out_features):
        super(CustomFC, self).__init__()
        self.fc = nn.Linear(in_features, out_features)
        self.kurtosis_neuron = KurtosisNeuron()

    def forward(self, x):
        
        fc_output = self.fc(x)
        
        kurtosis = self.kurtosis_neuron(fc_output)


According to the Figure, the hidden layer with 4 neurons is individually separated with other functions, which means you can simply index the output tensor of FC. KurtosisNeuron(fc_output[..., 0]), NegativeEntropy(fc_output[..., 1]), ... and so on. Did you mean this?
